# how do I load a gif file in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, gif

I can't find `System.Drawing` to use it. I found [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Drawing), but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the impression that it's because I'm coding a console app, but I'd still like to use the methods, and not simply load the gif file in binary mode or something like that. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx) to it in your project.